# How to use GoogleMaps InfoWindow() on a google.maps.Circle?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

The InfoWindow is not displayed if I use it in a loop.

Here is an example of how to use it with Marker:
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

I made similar but with Circle, code below, as you can see, `console.log` is working, but the `Infowindow` isn't.

What am I missing?

```
function initMap() {

    // Map settings, location : Barcelona, Spain
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 41.37, lng: 2.17},
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: true
    });

    // Circle distribution data : location, radius, data
    let distribution = {
        target_garden: {
            center: {lat: 41.371400, lng: 2.171942},
            population: 1,
            data: `<div>Text 01</div>`
        },
        target_wtc: {
            center: {lat: 41.373477, lng: 2.177650},
            population: 2,
            data: `<div>Text 02</div>`
        }
    };

    // Display 2 red circles on map
    let target;
    for (target in distribution) {

        let circle = new google.maps.Circle({

            // colors
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeOpacity: .2,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#f00',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,

            // position
            map: map,
            center: distribution[target].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(distribution[target].population) * 100,

            // settings
            draggable: false,
            editable: false,
            clickable: true

        });

        let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: distribution[target].data
        });

        // Event : on click a circle open infowindow
        circle.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, circle);
            console.log('on');
        });

    }

}
```

I expect a click on the red circle to open an InfoWindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the loop, it's that you're trying to anchor the `InfoWindow` to a `Circle`. This is from the Maps API documentation:

> **open([map, anchor])**
>
> Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. ***In the
>   core API, the only anchor is the Marker class*. However, an anchor can
>   be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property** and
>   optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the
>   pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions).

So, you could extend Circle somehow to make sure it has a position property, or you can set the position of `InfoWindow` explicitly (and not use anchor):

```
circle.addListener('click', function () {
  infowindow.setPosition(circle.center) 
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```